# Calling passport.authenticate from Server Side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

The following function call (which itself calls the `passport.use` function) works properly when called from the client side. However, because of how I am authenticating users, I do not need to call this function from the client but I would like to call it from the server side so that it still creates a cookie on the client side:

```
 app.post("/api/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
   if (err) {
     return next(err)
   }
   if (!user) {
     return res.status(400).send([user, "Cannot log in", info])
   }
   req.login(user, err => {
     res.send("Logged in")
   })
  })(req, res, next)
 })
```

How can I modify this function in order to call it from the server side and still creating a cookie on the client?

Comment: What do you mean by calling it from the server side ?, also you can send a cookie in the response to the client

Comment: Thank you Sven.hig. Actually, I am trying to call the logic that creates the cookie within the passport library, but I am having difficulty understand where exactly in the code the cookie is generated. Sorry, this is not very well explained in the question. Once created, yes I could send it back to the client.

Comment: if you are using express sessions, passport use that to serialize and deserialize user all what basicaly it does is use req.session and add the user id to the already existing session id, is there any particular reason you want to access the code that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of express sessions, [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/) uses that to `serialize` and `deserialize`  a user, what it does is  add the user id to the already existing session id,to set passport to do that you have to add this 2 functions to your strategy

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One only needs to add the following code in order to generate the cookie.

```
 req.login(add, err => {
   ...
 })
```

Thank you to Sven.hig for his help within the comments above.